# Speed of Python vs Julia for Game of Life. Why is Julia slow?

Tags: python, performance, julia

To compare the speed of `Julia` to `Python+numba`, I implemented [Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) in both languages.

For anyone who is not familiar with Game of Life: Start with a matrix of boolean entries, encoding whether a cell is *alive* or *dead*. Then, at every iteration, update the state of a cell based upon its value and the eight neighboring values.

1. If the cell is alive, and **exactly** two or three neighboring cells are alive, the cell stays alive.
2. If the cell is alive and **fewer than two** or **more than three** neighboring cells are alive, the cell dies.
3. If a cell is dead, and **exactly** three neighbors are alive, it becomes alive.
4. If none of the above applies, the cell keeps it state.

I chose a special initial condition called *Acorn*, just to make sure the population stays alive sufficiently long.

Here is the reference `Python+numba` code with the respective timing and output.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import time
from numba import njit

def acorn(n): # Initial condition
    state = np.zeros((n,n))
    mid = n//2
    state[mid,mid-2:mid+5] = 1
    state[mid,mid] = 0
    state[mid,mid+1] = 0
    state[mid+1,mid+1] = 1
    state[mid+2,mid-1] = 1
    return state>0
    
    
@njit
def update(s):
    dimx,dimy = s.shape
    nexts = np.copy(s)
    for i in range(1,dimx-1):
        for j in range(1,dimy-1):
            count = -1 if s[i,j] else 0
            for offi in [-1,0,+1]:
                for offj in [-1,0,+1]:
                    if s[i+offi,j+offj]:
                        count += 1
                            
            if s[i,j]:
                if count < 2 or count > 3:
                    nexts[i,j] = False
            else:
                if count ==3:
                    nexts[i,j] = True
    return nexts

    
def run(state,n):
    for i in range(n):
        state = update(state)  
    return state
    
n = 100
nruns = 1000
state = acorn(n)
t = time()
s = run(state,nruns)
dt = time() -t 
plt.pcolormesh(s)
plt.grid("on")
print("Elapsed time {:.5f} seconds".format(dt))
print("One run in {:.5f} seconds".format(dt/n))
print("{} runs per seconds".format(int(n/dt)))
plt.savefig("out.png")
```

Output (after a precompilation run):

```
Elapsed time 0.07883 seconds
One run in 0.00079 seconds
1268 runs per seconds
```

[image]

This seems reasonably fast on my Intel i5 notebook with 12gb of RAM and Python 3.8 and recent numpy + numba versions.

Next is the Julia code. I basically translated the Python code to Julia using my limited Julia knowledge.

```
using PyPlot

function acorn(n)
    mid = Int(n/2)+1
    state = zeros(n,n)
    state[mid,mid-2:mid+4] .= 1
    state[mid,mid] = 0
    state[mid,mid+1] = 0
    state[mid+1,mid+1] = 1
    state[mid+2,mid-1] = 1
    return state .> 0
end

function update!(nextstate::BitArray{2},state::BitArray{2})
    dimx,dimy = size(state)
    for i = 2:dimx-1
        for j = 2:dimy -1
            count = ifelse(state[i,j],-1,0)
            for offi in [-1,0,1]
                for offj in [-1,0,1]
                    if state[i+offi,j+offj]
                        count += 1
                    end
                end
            end
            
            if state[i,j]
               if count <2 || count > 3
                    nextstate[i,j] = false
                end
            else
                if count == 3
                    nextstate[i,j] = true
                end
            end
        end    
    end
end

function run(state,nsteps)
    nextstate = deepcopy(state)
    for i=1:nsteps
        update!(nextstate,state)
        state  = deepcopy(nextstate)
    end
    return state
end

nsteps = 1000
n = 100
state = acorn(n)
@time s = run(state,nsteps)
plt.pcolormesh(s)
plt.grid("on")
```

Output:

```
  1.746477 seconds (38.55 M allocations: 4.015 GiB, 7.56% gc time)
```

[image]

I see that there is a lot of memory allocation going on. But I am not sure about the best way to avoid this. Ultimately (unless I come up with a completely different algorithm), I do need two matrices (`state` array and its copy).

**What do I have to change in my Julia code to reach similar or better performance than my Python code?**

Comment: Did you profile the code to see where are the CPU cycles consumed? Not sure but deepcopy looks like is copy memory in deep and is a candidate for optimize

Comment: The `deepcopy`does not seem to be the problem. If I remove it from the inner loop (i.e., I basically repeat the first iteration `nsteps` times), the timing doesn't change much:
   `1.649412 seconds (38.42 M allocations: 4.007 GiB, 8.31% gc time)`. I will have to look into profiling tools, I'm not familiar with them yet.

Comment: Okay it seems that `for offi in [-1,0,1]` is the bottleneck. I can obviously replace it with `for i=-1:1` which speeds up things significantly. 
`0.202571 seconds (7.01 k allocations: 1.772 MiB)`

Comment: `n // 2` should become `n ÷ 2`, I believe. `Int(n/2)` fails for odd numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my "optimized" version of your code, I'm going down to about <s>32</s> 7 ms

I use `@btime` from `BenchmarkTools` to average multiple trys and avoid counting the compilation time

I made <s>4</s> 5 changes :

- switch from BitArray to Array{Int} (I don't know why it's faster though)
- update `state` with `.=` instead of a copy
- unroll the short loops
- update `nextstate` with a branchless `ifelse`
- (EDIT) `@inbounds` bypasses checking if indices are in the bounds of the array (only use it if you're sure the index isn't greater than the size of the array)

I also changed `count` to `counter` since `count` is a built-in function.

````
using PyPlot, BenchmarkTools

function acorn(n)
    mid = Int(n/2)+1
    state = zeros(Int, n, n) # <- specify Int (will be Float64 if not specified)
    state[mid,mid-2:mid+4] .= 1
    state[mid,mid] = 0
    state[mid,mid+1] = 0
    state[mid+1,mid+1] = 1
    state[mid+2,mid-1] = 1

    # I found that Array{Int} is faster than BitArray. Array{Bool} is slowest
    return state 
end

function update!(nextstate,state)
    dimx,dimy = size(state)
    for j in 2:dimy-1
        for i in 2:dimx-1
            # unroll loops
            @inbounds counter = state[i-1,j-1] + state[i-1,j] + state[i-1,j+1] +
                                state[i  ,j-1]                + state[i  ,j+1] +
                                state[i+1,j-1] + state[i+1,j] + state[i+1,j+1]
            
            # branchless if statement
            @inbounds nextstate[i,j] = ifelse(state[i,j] == 1, 1 < counter < 4, counter == 3)

        end    
    end
end

function run(state,nsteps)
    nextstate = copy(state)
    state = copy(state)

    for i in 1:nsteps
        update!(nextstate,state)

        # each value from nextstate is copied to state, instead of copying the whole array
        state .= nextstate
    end
    return state
end

nsteps = 1000
n = 100
state = acorn(n)
s = @btime run(state,nsteps)
plt.pcolormesh(s)
plt.grid("on")
```
````

Comment: Thank you! This was the kind of performance I expected but couldn't achieve. `Int` vs `BitArray` is strange though.
Thanks!

Comment: The downside of `BitArray`s is that they don't play well with vectorization since computers can only address bytes at a time. This means that re-ordering `getindex` and `setindex` can have really weird results.